# "Application not installed on your phone" when accessing activity using product flavors. Any Advice?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, package-name

My gradle has:

```
defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 26
        applicationId 'com.company.appname'
    }

buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt', 'proguard-ulivewallpaper.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt', 'proguard-ulivewallpaper.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

productFlavors {
        pro{
            applicationId = "com.company.appname.pro"
            flavorDimensions("default")
            buildConfigField("boolean", "demomode", "false")
        }
        free{
            applicationId = "com.company.appname.free"
            flavorDimensions("default")
            buildConfigField("boolean", "demomode", "true")
        }
    }
```

Not sure why but the app starts but when I want to access my settings activity, it says "Application not installed on your phone". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Long shot: http://www.droidforums.net/threads/application-not-installed-on-your-phone.176889/

Comment: No dice:( Problem persists...I've change back to no flavors and the app still has the same error. Any advice still?

Comment: Anything in the logcat with more info?

Comment: No error in the logcat. Since I was using Unity, I went ahead and recompiled my project and added the files a folder at a time to make sure I wasn't getting the same error. Never found out what was the issue though.